# Help with PHP array (EZPDF)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to output mysql data to a pdf using ezpdf. I have successfully generated the first part of my report but the second part a lot of columns and of course won't across the page. The diagram below will probably explain what I'm trying to do.

Example of the current layout:

---

|---**HEADER**--|---**HEADER2**--|---**HEADER3**--|---**HEADER4**--|---**HEADER5**--|

| USERNAME1 | DATAFIELD1 | DATAFIELD2 | DATAFIELD3 | DATAFIELD3 |

| USERNAME2 | DATAFIELD1 | DATAFIELD2 | DATAFIELD3 | DATAFIELD3 |

| USERNAME3 | DATAFIELD1 | DATAFIELD2 | DATAFIELD3 | DATAFIELD3 |

---

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

---

|----**HEADER1**---|---**HEADER2**---|

| USERNAME1 | DATAFIELD1 |

|---**HEADER3**---|---**HEADER4**---|---**HEADER5**---|

| DATAFIELD2 | DATAFIELD3 | DATAFIELD4 |

---

|----**HEADER1**---|---**HEADER2**---|

| USERNAME2 | DATAFIELD1 |

|---**HEADER3**---|---**HEADER4**---|---**HEADER5**---|

| DATAFIELD2 | DATAFIELD3 | DATAFIELD4 |

---

|----**HEADER1**---|---**HEADER2**---|

| USERNAME3 | DATAFIELD1 |

|---**HEADER3**---|---**HEADER4**---|---**HEADER5**---|

| DATAFIELD2 | DATAFIELD3 | DATAFIELD4 |

---

I hope that makes sense. If any one can help it would be very much appreciated.

Below is my test code

[test code](http://gamer4lyfe.com/dev/code.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [example code](http://gamer4lyfe.com/dev/tcpdfcode) that you posted, you are calling mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1) before the loop using  mysql_fetch_array($Recordset1), so the loop will have missed the first result. If you are doing the same in your other code then this will be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Cez!! I removed the first call and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,if you are not mantaining old code,  i advise you use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate PDF from php which offers a lot of functionality. for example converting html to PDF code withouth problems.

In you case you could create html tables and then convert them like in [this](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf) example

EDIT - in TCPDF you have to be very careful on how you markup your tables: from your link i see an error in your markup. the table you are trying to create should be like this:

```
$tbl = '
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<thead>
 <tr style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:#0000FF;">
  <td align="center"><b>USERNAME</b></td>
  <td align="center"><b>LASTNAME</b></td>
  <td align="center"><b>FIRSTNAME</b></td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr style="background-color:#FF0000;color:#FFFF00;">
     <td align="left">' .$username. '</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
';
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Nicola, I actually started out using TCPDF but was unsuccessful getting any of my reports to work. I have had success with EZPDF with several of my other reports. EZPDF was much easier for me to pick up.

Comment: @Brian B Where did you have problems with TCPDF?Anyway the thing i would do is use html tables to organize the data  and then output them as PDF

Comment: I had a lot of trouble looping the data in the tables. Only the first row of data would be displayed.

Comment: Here is the code I was using to test out fcpdf http://gamer4lyfe.com/dev/tcpdfcode.txt

Comment: @Brian B tomorrow i'll give a look at that! :)

Comment: Thanks I really appriciate it Nicola

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed the error and got the loop working. For some reason though it's cutting off the first row of data.

```
    $tbl = '
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
 <tr style="background-color:#666666;color:#FFFFFF;">
  <td align="center"><b>TITLE 1 HERE</b></td>
  <td align="center"><b>TITLE 2 HERE</b></td>
  <td align="center"><b>TITLE 3 HERE</b></td>
 </tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset1))
  {

$tbl = $tbl .'  <tr style="background-color:#000066;color:#FFFFFF;">
  <td align="left">Name: '.$row[lastname].', '.$row[firstname].'</td>
 </tr>'
    .'  <tr style="background-color:#CCCCCC;color:#000000;">
  <td align="left">'.ValLesson1.'</td> 
  <td align="left">'.ValLesson2.'</td>
  <td align="left">'.ValLesson3.'</td>
  </tr>'
 .'<tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;">
 <td align="left">'.$row[most_valuable_lesson].'</td>
 <td align="left">'.$row[second_valuable_lesson].'</td>
 <td align="left">'.$row[third_valuable_lesson].'</td>
 </tr>'
    .'  <tr style="background-color:#CCCCCC;color:#000000;">
  <td align="left">'.CourseStrengths.'</td>
  <td align="left">'.CourseWeakness.'</td>
 </tr>'
 .'<tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;">
 <td align="left">'.$row[course_strength].'</td>
 <td align="left">'.$row[course_weakness].'</td>
 </tr>'
; }
$tbl = $tbl . '</table>'; 

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

any ideas?

Comment: See my answer regarding why you are missing a row